# Overriding bean reference using PropertyOverrrideConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

According to [Spring documentation on PropertyOverrideConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer) you can't override bean references with property override configurer mechanism. That is, you can only provide literal values:

> Specified override values are always
>   literal values; they are not
>   translated into bean references. This
>   convention also applies when the
>   original value in the XML bean
>   definition specifies a bean reference.

**What is the workaround if I still wanted to re-configure wiring using overrriding properties files?**

I know I can fall back to injecting not the referenced bean but its name instead. Then I could override the wired bean name using property override mechanism. But that solution implies relying on Spring - `ApplicationContextAware` interface and its `getBean(String)` method. Anything better?

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4905

Answer (score 1):

As skaffman mentioned in the comment of their answer, [spel](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) is the workaround you are asking for.

This example works for me:

Dog.java

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
    }

}
```

override.properties

```
#person.d=#{dog1}
person.d=#{dog2}
```

Person.java

```
@Component
public class Person {

    private Dog d = new Dog();

    {
        d.setName("buster");
    }

    public Dog getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(Dog d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext c = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("sandbox/spring/dog/beans.xml");
        System.out.println(c.getBean("person"));
    }

}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="sandbox.spring.dog"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer"
        p:locations="classpath:/sandbox/spring/dog/override.properties"/>

    <bean
        id="dog1"
        class="sandbox.spring.dog.Dog"
        p:name="rover"/>

    <bean
        id="dog2"
        class="sandbox.spring.dog.Dog"
        p:name="spot"/>        

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` with `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. The two are related and very similar, but have different behaviour, including the latter having the ability to do things like this:

```
<property name="myProp">
   <ref bean="${x.y.z}" />
</property>
```

where `x.y.z` is a property containing a bean name.

So you *can* use externalised properties to alter your wiring with a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

**edit:** Another alternative is to abandon XML config altogether, and use [`@Bean`-style config in Java](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). This gives full flexibility of java's expressive power, so you can pretty much do what you like.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of placeholders because I wanted to have a default wiring definition (in XML) and allow for overriding for someone not modifying my XML files. Doesn't it mean that if I used placeholders, I can't provide a default value in XML?

Comment: @Grzegorz: You should be able to rustle up something useful with SpEL: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html